# Postfix 554 Relay access denied Error

Tags: linux, smtp, jira, postfix-mta, mail-server

I am trying to setup postfix version 2.8.17 on centOS and I am getting 554 Relay access denied error while trying to send mail from Jira (myhost.com/jira), which is another domain on the same host(myhost.com).

Output of postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10240000
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, $mydomain
mydomain = myhost.com
myhostname = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
```

SMTP debug trace in JIRA:

```
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<jira@myhost.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<user@myhost.com>
554 5.7.1 <user@myhost.com>: Relay access denied
DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix it with following steps:

1. Run
   /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --without-spam
2. Start service
   /etc/init.d/pc-remote start
3. Check that 'Mail service' is enabled for the subscription at Subscription -> Mail -> Change Settings Activate mail service on domain. If it is not enabled, turn it on.